# Install SuiteCloud IDE into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, netsuite

I am trying to Install **SuiteCloud IDE** into **Eclipse**.

I followed as per instructions like.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aK72dRP24qw

https://riptutorial.com/netsuite/example/13251/eclipse-suitecloud-ide-setup

I am giving URL : http://netsuite.com/download/ide/update_18_2

But when I go on help -> Install New Software, In second step I am getting below error.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: SuiteCloud IDE 2018.1.2 (com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2018.1.2)
  Missing requirement: SuiteCloud IDE 2018.1.2 (com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.app 2018.1.2) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.2' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: SuiteCloud IDE Main Application 2018.1.2 (com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.app.feature.feature.group 2018.1.2)
    To: com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.app [2018.1.2]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: SuiteCloud IDE 2018.1.2 (com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2018.1.2)
    To: com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.app.feature.feature.group [2018.1.2]
```

Kindly help me, how to resolve this error. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue in this past. Rather than fixing the Eclipse errors, I opted to installing another version of Eclipse and installing SuiteCloud IDE after doing this worked fine.

First, navigate to: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Scroll down the list and locate "Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers"

Install to your root directory (C://)

Then try installing SuiteCloud IDE again. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.9.2'` is the key part of this error.

This is saying that at least verion 3.9.2 of the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` plug-in is required.

Version 3.9.2 of this plugin was first included in Eclipse Kepler (4.3), so you need to be running at least this version of Eclipse. Older versions won't work.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I don't know how to install this plugin : ). If you don't mind then can you please help me.

Comment: You don't install this plug-in, it is included as part of Eclipse (the versions with Java support). But you must use a recent version of Eclipse to get the correct version. You can't install it in older versions.